# How to get GridView RowIndex when checkbox is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple gridview. Every row has some boundFields and a checkbox. The checkbox has AutoPostBack=True and fires a method (chkPlanned_OnCheckedChanged) using the  OnCheckedChanged event.

```
     <asp:GridView ID="gvAudits" runat="server" EnablePersistedSelection="true"
            AllowSorting="True" CssClass="DDGridView"
            RowStyle-CssClass="td" HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" CellPadding="6" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AuditId" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="gvAudits_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvAudits_RowCommand"
            OnDataBound="OnDataBound">

            <Columns>



                <asp:BoundField DataField="AuditDate" SortExpression="AuditDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderText="Audit Date" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division Owner" SortExpression="DivisionOwner" ItemStyle-Width="140px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="width: 140px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                            <%# Eval("DivisionOwner") %>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Main Auditee" SortExpression="MainAuditee" ItemStyle-Width="140px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="width: 140px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                            <%# Eval("MainAuditee") %>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalFindings" SortExpression="TotalFindings" HtmlEncode="False" HeaderText="Total <br />Findings " ItemStyle-Width="25px">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="NoMajorFindings" SortExpression="NoMajorFindings" HtmlEncode="False" HeaderText="Major <br />Findings " ItemStyle-Width="25px">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>




                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Potential" SortExpression="Planned">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkPlanned" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Planned"))%>' AutoPostBack="True"   OnCheckedChanged="chkPlanned_OnCheckedChanged" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="50px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="50px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <asp:BoundField DataField="AuditId" HeaderText="AuditId" SortExpression="AuditId"
                    ReadOnly="True" Visible="False">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                            OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");' CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>


            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                There are currently no items in this table.
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

This method in the C# code behind then gets the rowIndex using the following logic:

```
protected void chkPlanned_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) sender;
  GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow) chk.Parent.Parent;
  var dataKey = gvAudits.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex];
}
```

Everything was working perfect then I needed to add in a grouped column header which I did programmatically as follows:

```
    protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
        cell.Text = "";
        cell.ColumnSpan = 5;
        row.Controls.Add(cell);

        cell = new TableHeaderCell();
        cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
        cell.Text = "Finding Status";
        row.Controls.Add(cell);

        cell = new TableHeaderCell();
        cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
        cell.Text = "Finding Type";
        row.Controls.Add(cell);


        cell = new TableHeaderCell();
        cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
        cell.Text = "";
        row.Controls.Add(cell);

        row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3AC0F2");
        gvAudits.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row);
    }
```

The problem is, now when I click a checkbox after the grouping header was added, I cannot get the RowIndex from the codebehind any longer. gr.RowIndex always returns 0. Any ideas why this is?

Perhaps there is a way to add a grouping to the gridview header in ASPX rather than in code behind and this will then fix the problem?
[image: Header with groupings added]

Comment: check my provided answer..

Comment: Always use `chk.NamingContainer` instead of `chk.Parent.Parent`.

Comment: @DeadlyDee got solution..

Answer (score 3):

Use below code, Hope it will solve your problem

```
public void Chacked_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GridViewRow Row = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent);
string id = grd1.DataKeys[Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
string cellvalue = Row.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

OR use

```
 CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender; 
 GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer;
 string id = GridView1.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
 string cellvalue = GridView1.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
```

Comment: Hi this solution doesn't work, its still giving me a RowIndex = 0.

Comment: @DeadlyDee Yes if u will select first row then rowindex will be 0... if u want only row indx then u will get by this line easily-> int selRowIndex = ((GridViewRow)(((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent)).RowIndex;

Comment: Nope- I tried this also but its not working. If I remove the grouping header EVERYTHING works. But I need the

Comment: @DeadlyDee I have checked that and I can see on line in your rowbound ->  gvAudits.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row); -- why u bound header controls on every row? I think this line cause problem

Comment: Hi, the header is only bound once, as the image shows the grouping header is inserted above the main header. As far as I can see the implementation is correct and I don't see anything wrong with it? Thanks for checking :)